# string.length() causing trouble

Tags: c++, string

I'm really baffled by this simple problem.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "bb";
    int counter;
    for (counter = str.length() - 1;  counter >= str.length() - 2;  counter--)
    {
        std::cout << "counter: " << counter << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Basically, it should only print two lines and then terminate the program, but it keeps printing lines. In fact, the loop is not stopped at counter = -1 and that's weird! Why does that happen?

Comment: Using `void main()` in global namespace in C++ is illegal. You should use `int main(void)` instead.

Comment: @MikeCAT: What do you mean by illegal?! It's working fine.

Comment: @user3257464 It's not allowed by the spec. Your compiler may allow it, but it's non-portable and you shouldn't do it.

Comment: @user3257464 Robbery also works fine, and still is illegal. If something works for you, it does not mean that it will work anytime everywhere.

Comment: @lisyarus: I suppose that when you call it illegal, there is a system that prevents me from doing this thing in Visual Studio. For example chewing gum is illegal in Singapore, but you could not say the general sentence: "chewing gum is illegal"!

Comment: @user3257464 That's not what this is. The formal language specification says this is illegal. To use your analogy, this would be like sitting in a bar in Singapore which turns a blind eye to chewing gum, then assuming that you can go and do so outside the police station without spending the night in a cell.

Comment: @user3257464 Nice point :)  However, when doing programming, you usually want your program not to cause any problems when moved from Visual Studio to anything else. Continuing your example, imagine a child who can only remember to chew the gum or not to, regardless of his location, and you know he may accidentally arrive at Singapore. What will you tell him, provided that you don't want him to appear inside Singapore prison?

Comment: @user3257464 If you are going to *code under Visual Studio*, go on. But if you are going to *code in C++*, you have to rely on the language specs, not on the behavior of this particular IDE.

Comment: @lisyarus: you used an analogy first and I just wanted to show that these different things must not be mixed together. OK. This sentence convinced me: "The formal language specification says this is illegal.". Now, it's a better response than "it's illegal" in general. By the way, my question was another thing and I think we are getting away form the main issue ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::string.length()` is unsigned, so `counter` in `counter >= str.length() - 2` is converted to unsigned value and the formula won't be true.

Try using `counter + 2 >= 0 && counter + 2 >= str.length()` instead.

Comment: @RSahu It won't solve this directly. It is also good to cast `str.length()` to proper signed type.

Comment: Could you please explain it more? str.length()-2 would be equal to zero, no?  So why is the formula going to be wrong?

Comment: No unsigned integer is less than 0.

Comment: Got it! Thanks :-)